# Heroku push rejected - Slug compilation failed: failed to compile Ruby app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

It would be really helpful if someone could tell me how to proceed on this. I am following the steps in the below link to deploy the app mentioned in this link.
http://installfest.railsbridge.org/installfest/deploy_a_rails_app

However, the deployment is failing with an error message :

```
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        NameError: undefined local variable or method `hRails' for main:Object
remote:        Tasks: TOP => environment
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to desolate-peak-2535.
remote:
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/desolate-peak-2535.git'
```

Here is the server log:

```
015-08-20T07:54:20.729142+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: failed to compile Ruby app
015-08-20T08:21:44.563972+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
015-08-20T08:21:44.563994+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: failed to compile Ruby app
015-08-20T08:26:26.742224+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: failed to compile Ruby app
015-08-20T08:26:26.742136+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
```

Comment: search your project for a "hRails" string and replace it with "Rails"

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to reproduce this locally by running `rake assets:precompile`. Line 3 of your error log. Then the error clearly says this failed, where it says: `Precompiling assets failed.` And finally, somewhere you are using the variable `hRails` which is not found. Likely a typo and you mean `Rails`. Search your project for `hRails` and that will be where the error is.